# tkinter: How to get value in optionsmenu?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to use the `OptionMenu` in order to assign a command via a button widget, however I am unable to get the proper value for some reason.
So my code goes something along those lines:

```
root = tk.Tk()
choice1 = tk.StringVar()
choice1.set("DEFAULT")
options1 = tk.OptionMenu(root, choice1, "text1", "text2")
options1.place(x=320, y=355)

start_button = tk.Button(root, text="start")
start_button.place(x=200, y=400)
if choice1.get() == "text1":
    start_button.configure(command=lambda: print("some text"))
root.mainloop()
```

And it doesn't work if the option is on `"text1"`, however if I change `if choice1.get() == "text1"` to `if choice1.get() == "DEFAULT"` then it seems to work, but for every option, not only default.

How do I assign a specific command to an external button based on what's selected in the `OptionMenu` widget?

By the way, if I change the command to print `choice1.get()` it does print out the correct option (while I just assign the command to the button widget without an `if` statement).

Edit: 
As per request, the game is connect 4, and the options are Human and PC. 
What I'm trying to do is have 2 option menus, one for player 1 (Yellow) one for player 2 (Red). Once Human vs Human is selected, the I would like the start button to direct me to a specific function.

Here is what I wrote (needs editing, sorry for how it looks):

```
    self.__root = root
    self.__global_size = 70
    self.game = Game()

    menu_draw = tk.Canvas(self.__root, width=500, height=500)
    menu_draw.pack()
    self.__root.resizable(0, 0)
    welcome_label = tk.Label(self.__root, text=WELCOME_MSG, font=("Comic Sans MS", 20), bg="White", fg="Blue",
                             relief="groove")
    menu_draw.create_oval((100, 250), (200, 350), fill="red")
    menu_draw.create_oval((300, 250), (400, 350), fill="Yellow")
    welcome_label.place(x=60, y=40)
    choice1 = tk.StringVar()
    choice1.set("Yellow")
    options1 = tk.OptionMenu(self.__root, choice1, "Human", "PC")
    options1.configure(bg="Yellow")
    options1.place(x=320, y=355)
    choice2 = tk.StringVar()
    choice2.set("Red")
    options2 = tk.OptionMenu(self.__root, choice2, "Human", "PC")
    options2.configure(bg="Red")
    options2.place(x=100, y=355)
    start_button = tk.Button(self.__root, text="START", font=("Comic Sans MS", 20), bg="White", fg="Blue")
    start_button.place(x=200, y=400)
    if choice1.get() == "Human" and choice2.get() == "Human":
        start_button.configure(command=lambda: self.mainm(self.__root))
    self.__root.mainloop()
```

But ya, it doesn't work. If I replace both `"Human"` to `"Yellow"` and `"Red"` respectively, then it works, but it works for every option that is selected.
`self.mainm` directs do another function that destroys the old root and creates a new one (to create the board and rules).

Comment: Hmm looks complicated haha, I haven't really learnt some of the things there and this is for school work, is there a simpler way without re-defining the options menu? Thanks by the way

Comment: Hi, I've edited with the code I wrote

Comment: But why if I change `command=lambda: self.mainm(self.__root)` to `command=print(choice1.get()`) it does work, and prints Human or PC (based on the current option)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python with Tkinter, how can I make a button press do a different thing depending on which option is selected in the option menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376791/using-python-with-tkinter-how-can-i-make-a-button-press-do-a-different-thing-de)

Comment: Awesome, works now! seems like configuring didn't work, but having the command in the button widget works. Thanks for the help :)